# Unable to load DLL ‘ABCpdf9-64.dll’. The specified module could not be found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, abcpdf9

I have installed abcPDF 9.1.1.5  version on my local machine and everything works perfectly.
but I deploy code to windows server 2008 R2 machine i get this error.

any one guide me what could be the issue.

I have already explored following articles and this is not working for me.

[1](https://www.ablemods.com/blog/post/2012/08/31/ABCPdf-Unable-to-load-DLL-ABCpdf8-64dll-The-specified-module-could-not-be-found-%28Exception-from-HRESULT-0x8007007E%29.aspx) and [2](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/04/19/unable-to-load-dll-abcpdfce6dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception-from-hresult-0x8007007e/)

Code:

```
string strFileName = Invoice.InvoiceNumber;
XSettings.License = "something-something-something";
Doc m_GeneratePDF = new Doc();
m_GeneratePDF.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
StringBuilder strBuilderHTML = new StringBuilder();
string strHTML;
strBuilderHTML.Append("<HTML>");
strBuilderHTML.Append("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />");
strBuilderHTML.Append("<head>");
//strBuilderHTML.Append("<link href='styles/Site.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
strBuilderHTML.Append("</head>");
strBuilderHTML.Append("<BODY>");
strHTML = strBuilderHTML.ToString();

theID = m_GeneratePDF.AddImageHtml(strHTML);
```

That are relevant to my problem.

Comment: There are a bunch of DLLs you have to copy.  Miss one and you'll get this error.  If you can't figure out the manual installation instructions in the manual then send them a twenty dollar bill with your support request typed on the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after fighting with this issue 3 days i solved it.

here is what i did:
1) I was publishing the code from 32 bit machine windows 8
2) my server was windows server 2008 R2 64bit machine.

=>I enabled 32bit applications from iis options which never solved my problem as per googling
then i 
=> set "Load User profile" which again never solved my problem.
=>then somebody told me give full rights to abcPDF and abcGeco dlls on your server that also never worked.

Then i finally, compiled my code from 64bit machine OR i copied 64bit ABCpdf & ABCGeco dll files from bin folder into my published folder that finally worked.

Comment: I tried the approaches in your post, but found that

Comment: I had this same issue.  I made a mistake and installed the 64 bit version first.  Then I installed the 32.  I got the error. However, after changing the Enable 32 bit applications options on the IIS server it worked. Be sure to restart your app pool after making the change or it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Just want do add my solution:**
Install ABCpdf (in my case "ABCpdf.NET64.exe") on the server,  that´s all. (You could probably copy some dll files around to fix the problem)

**for the error:** 
Unable to load DLL 'ABCpdf10-64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

**Environment (all x64)**
Prod:
Windows Server 2012 R2
Dev:
Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be too helpful here.  But I struggled with this as well from an inherited project after a Windows Update broke a very old implementation of ABCPDF within an ASP.NET web application.  I am not saying you should repeat these steps, but I am putting all these steps in here in case it helps someone else identify what they might need to do. Also, I was on ABCPDF10, but I don't see why this wouldn't work for any version.

1. I installed 64-bit ABCPDF10, and then installed 32-bit ABCPDF10 via the MSI for each.
2. I then copied the files in their respective C:/Program Files directories into the bin/ of my project manually per ABCPDFs instructions.  This didn't work for me because when I went to build in VS2015 it couldn't see the .DLL for some reason.
3. I then uninstalled it by deleting the files out of my project bin/ manually and then using Add/Remove Apps in Server2012R2.
4. I then used Nuget to download ABCPDF and that worked and it could build.  But I still needed ABCPDF.Gekco
5. I then used Nuget to try and install ABCPDF.Gecko.  This downloaded it, but it didn't install it fully.  I manually copied over the missing .dlls and .exe into the bin/ directory and Built the project.
6. It is at this point I got stuck with the error message from the original poster.
7. What worked for me here is I left the Project and bin/ directory alone and I then used the .MSI installer and re-installed only the x64 version to the C:/ like any other program.  I didn't have to copy any files.  I just re-built the project and boom!  That worked.

It *feels to me* like a registry key/path issue.  But I have no idea if that is right.

Hopefully that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me.

1. Install newest version / version that the error complains is missing

> Unable to load DLL ‘ABCpdf***12***-64.dll’. The specified module could not be found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

- Via: https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-download.aspx

2. Build and Run. If this works, then congrats. Solved. Skip all other steps.

   - If this doesn't work, you should get an error complaining about a version mismatch. And it should list the version that it requires. Go to step 3
3. Install correct version from NuGet gallery: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ABCpdf.ABCGecko/12.3.0.5
4. Go to ***..\solution\packages\ABCpdf.[version number]\build\*** and copy ***ABCpdf12-64.dll*** file to ***..\solution\project\Bin\***
5. Build and Run

This worked for me